# 2 Values inside 1 foreach with php

Tags: php, string, forms, foreach

I have a problem with my contact form.

I use dynamic form fields inside my contact form and this work perfect.

The problem now it looks not good in the Email.

It looks like: `Value Value1 Value Value1...`

But I want it so:

```
Value Value1

Value Value1
```

...

My code:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    
    $ware = $_POST['ware'];
    $wareString = "";
    foreach($ware as $value) {
        $wareString .= $value;
    }
    $warenanzahl = $_POST['warenanzahl'];
    $warenanzahlString = "";
    foreach($warenanzahl as $value1) {
        $warenanzahlString .= $value1;
    }
    
    $from = 'Form'; 
    $to = 'test@test.de'; 
    $subject = 'Message';
    
    $body ="Store: Test\n Message:\n $wareString $warenanzahlString";
```

Can anyone help me please. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to combine the two arrays, so it's `$ware[n] . $warenanzahl[n]`?

Comment: Yes i have a Order form with dynamic text fields. Every line is the Productname and the quantity. Now after every line i want a line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the 2 arrays are of the same length and you can do this

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $wareString = "";

    foreach($_POST['ware'] as $key => $value) {
        // the ' = ' . is optional
        $wareString .= $value . ' = ' . $_POST['warenanzahl'][$key] . '<br>';
        // or if it is not a HTML email 
        $wareString .= $value . ' = ' . $_POST['warenanzahl'][$key] . PHP_EOL;

    }

    $from = 'Form'; 
    $to = 'test@test.de'; 
    $subject = 'Message';

    $body ="Store: Test\n Message:\n $wareString";

    . . .
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to answer, thanks for saving me the trouble!

Comment: Hmm.. then try replacing `'<br>'` with `"\n"` or `PHP_EOL`